# How to use redis with gearman for persistence

Tags: redis, persistence, gearman, hiredis

How can I use Gearman with redis for persistent queue?

I am trying to run it for centos7. 
I have Gearman working. 
On running

```
gearmand -h
```

I can see support for 
libsqlite3, 
Postgres, 
libtokyocabinet and 
MySQL.

I've installed **hiredis** using yum as per various forums although i cant figure out how to run it through terminal. 
I downloaded tar file for gearman and tried running this command inside the gearman folder to no avail.

```
./configure --enable-FEATURE sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build gearmand with hiredis persistence queue you have to install `libhiredis-devel` on CentOS or `libhiredis-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu package.

Insure `./configure  --enable-hiredis` output contains

```
checking hiredis/hiredis.h usability... yes
checking hiredis/hiredis.h presence... yes
checking for hiredis/hiredis.h... yes
checking for main in -lhiredis... yes
```

To run gearmand with redis as queue type, run:
`gearmand --verbose DEBUG --queue-type redis`